# Splitting input string into words and saving to an array

Tags: c, parsing, text

I have been going at this for hours, and I can't figure out what the problem in my code is.
I'm currently writing a very simple assembler for a custom instruction set architecture. This assembler takes an input file and simply parses line by line. In the parsing process, I intend to split each line up by spaces, writing the tokens to an array for processing. Below is some of the code to do that:

```
    char** tokens = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    char* linecpy = strcpy(linecpy, line);

    char* tok_ptr = strtok(linecpy, " ");
    int tokenid = 0;
    while(tok_ptr) {
        tokens = (char**) realloc(tokens, (tokenid+1) * sizeof(char*));
        tokens[tokenid] = tok_ptr;
        tokenid++;
        tok_ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

To test that this is accurately working, I'm having it print out each token sequentially from the array, and I'm finding random splits in the middle of the tokens that shouldn't be there. Here is an example:

Line from assembly file:

```
    jsr fibloop      ; jump to the main program loop
```

Expected Output from splitting by spaces:

```
    jsr
    fibloop
    ;
    jump
    to
    the
    main
    program
    loop
```

Actual Output:

```
    jsr
    fibloo
    p
    ;
    jump
    to
    the
    main
    pr
    ogram
    l
    oop
```

I've spent so long trying to solve this to no avail, and feedback on how to potentially solve this would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: Solution to this was pointed out by Clifford and 4386427, the problem was that linecpy had no memory allocated to it, and strcpy doesn't directly return a new string as I had incorrect assumed. The working code has been put below, and I've included a comment filter to stop tokenization after the parser hits a comment character, something pointed out by Clifford

```
    char** tokens = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    char* linecpy = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);

    strcpy(linecpy, line);

    char* tok_ptr = strtok(linecpy, " ");
    int tokenid = 0;
    while(tok_ptr) {
         /* 
            If a token starts with a comment character then we stop tokenization, 
            as everything after will be commented and is of no use to the parser
        */
        if(tok_ptr[0] == ';') break;
        tokens = (char**) realloc(tokens, (tokenid+1) * sizeof(char*));
        tokens[tokenid] = tok_ptr;
        tokenid++;
        tok_ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    // free memory allocated to tokens after parsing
    free(tokens);
```

Hopefully this helps anyone with the same problem I had, the quick responses given by members of this community was extremely helpful. Thanks guys!

Comment: Anyone answering this is likely going to need a complete example that produces the output illustrated.  At least we would need to know what the actual input was to give that output.

Comment: Noted, I included the line from the assembly file being read from

Comment: You may be making this parser more complex than necessary.  Everything from `;` to the end of the line should probably be either discarded or considered a single token.  What if  the comment is `;jump to ...` ? (i.e. no space after `;`)

Comment: My problem with this was simple just splitting the text up by spaces to be processed in the first place, my intent for dealing with that is immediately stop parsing the line if the first character of a token is a ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* linecpy = strcpy(linecpy, line);
```

is illegal. `linecpy` has no allocated memory. You need

```
char* linecpy = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
strcpy(linecpy, line);
```

Besides that:

```
char** tokens = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

should be

```
char** tokens = NULL;
```

Comment: That did the trick, my misunderstanding of strcpy and memory allocation in general caused the mishap, as I tested putting the regular input line to be tokenized and it worked completely as intended. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CodeKraken You can also take a look at the non-standard `strdup` function... it allocates memory for you.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy()` doe not allocate memory for the *destination string*, it needs to be allocated before calling `strcpy()` - nothing good will happen by copying to an *unitialised pointer*; I am surprised it did not seg-fault right there.

```
char linecpy[MAX_LINE_LEN] ;
strcpy( linecpy, line ) ;
```

or even

```
char* linecpy = malloc( strlen(line) + 1 ) ;
strcpy( linecpy, line ) ;
```

The following example outputs as you expect, with just teh above change:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char line[] = "jsr fibloop      ; jump to the main program loop" ;
    
    char** tokens = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    
    char* linecpy = malloc( strlen(line) + 1 ) ;
    strcpy( linecpy, line ) ;
    
    char* tok_ptr = strtok(linecpy, " ");
    int tokenid = 0;
    while(tok_ptr) {
        tokens = (char**) realloc(tokens, (tokenid+1) * sizeof(char*));
        tokens[tokenid] = tok_ptr;
        tokenid++;
        tok_ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }


    for( int i = 0; i < tokenid; i++) printf( "%s\n", tokens[i] ) ;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it was the lack of a segfault that kept me from noticing that. I haven't had too much experience in the form of text parsing and memory manipulation with C, so something small like that slipping by me makes sense. Apologies for that! The quick responses from you and 4386427 certainly helped a lot!